# Bluetooth with asus z370 and ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04

Is it possible to have bluetooth with this motherboard which is supposed to have integrated bluetooth?

If yes, could you please help me on this?

Thanks!

---

Update

Here is the result for `lspci -knn | grep Net; lsusb`

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a) 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:1872 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Hi, I updated the question with your request :)

Comment: There really is a BT device `8087:0029 Intel Corp.` . It should work. If it doesn't, please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/0029/' RS=` and `dmesg | grep -i blue`. Also check if the device is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes this corresponds to an additional bluetooth/wifi card I just added (intel AX200). But I was wondering if I could use the motherboard instead. Moreover bluetooth service is unstable/unreliable. Do you know If I can do something about it ? Sometimes the bluetooth service just stops working.

Comment: I don't see any other BT device. Probably it is optional and you don't have it.